# How to move a HighStock cloned tooltip while/after zooming or resizing

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, clone

I know how to clone a HighStock tooltip and keep it visible. It is fine as long as the chart geometry is static.

However when the chart is zoomed/panned/resized, the static cloned tooltip is no longer consistent with the plots. How can I update its position? I suppose in an eventhandler in the xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes function, but I am stuck now.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/xhLtr2cg/

```
$(function () {
    cloneToolTip = null;
    
    chart = new Highcharts.stockChart('container',{
        chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Click on the highlighted point to clone the tooltip.<br>Then zoom or resize. How to update the cloned tooltip position?'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() { 
                            if (cloneToolTip)
                            { 
                               chart.container.firstChild.removeChild(cloneToolTip);
                            }
                            cloneToolTip = chart.tooltip.label.element.cloneNode(true);
                            chart.container.firstChild.appendChild(cloneToolTip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis:{
                events: {
                    afterSetExtremes: function() {
                        // ***** probably update the cloneToolTip position here *****
                   }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [1,4,3,4,2,3,1]  
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better way to trigger the tooltip on click and keep it visible while redrawing the chart is this config: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e8aboymw/

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'hide', function(proceed) {});

Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function(proceed, point, event, click) {
  if (click) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  }
});

let curPoint,
  curE;

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        if (curPoint && curE) {
          this.tooltip.refresh(curPoint, curE, true)

        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175],
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          curPoint = this;
          curE = e;
          this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this, e, true);
        }
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

More about the wrap: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts#wrapping-up-a-plugin

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your suggestion but it does not work in my environment, which is angular 8.2, highcharts 8.1.2 with the official Highcharts Angular package 2.7.0.

The typescript compiler complains:

Argument of type '(proceed: any, point: any, event: any, click: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WrapProceedFunction'.ts(2345)

Comment: Here is a demo which shows how to wrap an Highcharts core in the Angular environment. https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-custom-plugin maybe it will help you to implement the above custom solution into your project.